# No action respond to id in rails routing problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I am adding a functionality of resetting password in my rails application

In my users page , i have all the users listing

If i am logging in as a admin below the users a link to reset password to users are available which will set a default password to them

```
  <%= link_to "Reset Password",reset_password_user_path  %>
```

In my controller users

```
    def reset_password

     @user = params[:user]
     puts "which user #{@user}"
     @user.password = "12345"
  if @user.save
    flash[:notice] = "Password successfully reseted"
    redirect_to user_path
  else
    flash[:error]= "Password not reste!"
    redirect_to user_path
  end

  end
```

In my routes

```
   map.resources :users, :member => {:reset_password => :post}
```

When i run my users page , i am getting the error as below

```
  reset_password_user_url failed to generate from {:action=>"reset_password", :controller=>"users"} - you may have ambiguous routes, or you may need to supply additional parameters for this route.  content_url has the following required parameters: ["users", :id, "reset_password"] - are they all satisfied?
```

WHen i gave the link as

```
   <%= link_to "Reset Password",reset_password_user_path(user)  %>
```

then i am getting the error as No action respond to 2

```
  Processing UsersController#2 (for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-03-14 11:38:33) [GET]
   Parameters: {"action"=>"2", "id"=>"reset_password", "controller"=>"users"}
```

How to resolve this..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternatively `<%= link_to "Reset Password", reset_password_user_path(user), :method => "post" %>` assuming you have Prototype or jQuery.

This way you are still posting to the action as it makes changes to the user.

Answer (score 0):

Try with get method instead of post in routes.